# Run python script over telnet from windows

Tags: python, linux, automation, raspberry-pi, telnet

I am using Raspberry Pi with PiFace as automation device. I have some python scripts in Raspberry. I need run the scripts remotely from Windows PC and I have to use Telnet... So my question is: How can I run any python script on Linux machine  remotely over telnet from windows PC. For example I  need run command like "python /home/automation.py" over telnet from Windows PC.

For your understanding: I can not use SSH/putty! I need control Pi from "closed" apliction on windows server. The application can send only ascii command via Telnet. So my question is how I can translate some ASCII command to bash command...

Can you help please?

I found some similar questions but that was about reversed communication.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you heard of SSH/[putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)

Comment: It is misunderstanding! I know SSH/putty...of course! I will try explain my issue better. Pi works as automation device (I can control Pi from webinterface or ssh) and I need to control it from windows server where is running some "closed" application which can send commands only via Telnet in ASCII... I can not use putty or other ssh client. I need control Pi from the mentioned application. I can send command like 0&#x0D;&#x0A via telnet. It means that I need translate command 0&#x0D;&#x0A from Aplication to command for PI (python /home/file.py)

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that you'll ever be able to ask this question in a way that makes it a good question for Stack Overflow. On the other hand, it *may* be more appropriate on the [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) exchange. Ultimately all you really need to do is write a socket server on your RPi that listens for whatever commands your app sends it.

Comment: Sounds like you need a python telnet server. Does it need to be fast? Create a python server using sockets and have it bind to port 23 if you cant specify the port from windows.